# React - bubble up state to change className on children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, event-bubbling

I have a hierarchy of data broken down into 6 columns for each tier of the hierarchy. As the user clicks through their selection, their selected location is highlighted via a dynamic css className and the corresponding list of data shows. I figured out how to make the highlight move for each selection. However, if the user starts back at the beginning of the hierarchy, it holds the last highlight in state.

For example, If I have a hierarchy of country, state, city and I selected USA, California, LA. If I select a different country, and then click back to USA, California will still be highlighted. How do I change the className across all columns?

I realize there are several similar posts about bubbling up state. I have not been able to figure out how to apply them to my scenario as I need to go up one more child than the usual examples.

Code structure:
App.js, LocationList.js, Location.js

LocationList.js

```
class LocationList extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            title: props.title,
            clicked: false,
         };
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick(selectedItem) { 
       this.props.onListClick(selectedItem) 
       this.setState({clicked: selectedItem})
    }

    isSelected(location){ //current selected item is highlighted
        if(location.LocationId === this.state.clicked.LocationId){
            return 'highlight'
        }
        else {return 'no_highlight'}
    } 

    return( ..//other info.. 
                 <Location
                    location={location}
                    key={location.LocationId+location.LocationName}
                    tier={this.props.level}
                    handler={this.handleClick}
                    highlightClass={this.isSelected(location)}
                  />
```

Location.js

```
class Location extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={
            locationsList: props.locationList
        }   
        this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);       
    }

    onClick(selectedItem) { 
        this.props.handler(this.props.location);
     };

  render() {
        let location = this.props.location;
        console.log(this.props)     

        return(
            <div 
                id="item"
                style={locationStyle}  
                key={location.LocationId} 
                value={location.Name} 
                level={location.Level}
                onClick={this.onClick}
                className={this.props.highlightClass}
            >
                {location.LocationName} 
            </div> 
        );
    }
  }
```

App.js - this is where I'm stuck

```
handleClick(selectedItem) {
// See value user clicked
console.log('Selected location: ', selectedItem) 
}

render() {
      return(
          <div className="row">
          <LocationList key="1" level="1" title="Country" lis={this.state.column Tier1} onListClick={this.handleClick}/>
          <LocationList key="2" level="2" title="State" lis={this.state.column Tier2} onListClick={this.handleClick}/>
          <LocationList key="3" level="3" title="City" lis={this.state.column Tier3} onListClick={this.handleClick}/>
  </div>
 );
```

}

App.css

```
.no_highlight {
  background-color: transparent
}
.highlight {
  background-color: #007dc34d
}
```

Comment: While it's possible to bubble the state up multiple levels, the better option might be to move to a more robust state management solution, like [Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux).

Comment: Brett, you called it. Next steps are to implement Redux.

Answer (score 1):

Store the whole selection in the `App` state, then pass down the appropriate selection to the corresponding `LocationList`. Finally, implement different handlers for `LocationList` clicks to reset the state

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      ...
      selection: {
        country: null,
        state: null,
        city: null
      }
    };

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(getSelection) {
    return location => {
      const selection = getSelection(location);
      this.setState({
        selection: Object.assign({}, this.state.selection, selection)
      };
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        ...
        <LocationList title="Country"
                      selection={this.state.selection.country}
                      onClick={this.handleClick(country => ({ country, state: null, city: null }))}
                      // other props
        />
        <LocationList title="State"
                      selection={this.state.selection.state}
                      onClick={this.handleClick(state => ({ state, city: null }))}
                      // other props
        />
        <LocationList title="City"
                      selection={this.state.selection.city}
                      onClick={this.handleClick(city => ({ city }))}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```